# Excel formula required on start and finish date

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, formula

I am looking to find a formula to show a "Start date" based on the first date entry and also "Finish date" if the there is no date against a person's name since last two months. I.e August = left.

see image example of data

[image: Names & Dates Image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate the **Start date** use the **MINIFS** function.

```
=MINIFS($B$2:$B$17,$A$2:$A$17,$D2)
```

To calculate the **Last Check date** use the **EDATE** function.

```
=EDATE(TODAY(),-2)
```

To calculate the **Leave date** use the **MAXIFS** function with the results of the **EDATE** function.
If it returns a zero, then use it again to get the last date for the person or return a blank.

```
=IF(MAXIFS($B$2:$B$17,$A$2:$A$17,$D2,$B$2:$B$17,">"&$H$2)=0,MAXIFS($B$2:$B$17,$A$2:$A$17,$D2),"")
```

[image: Screenshot of data and formulas]

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a simple `MINIFS()` function, as in following screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Works for start date thank you. is there a way to capture leave date excluding current month&previous month.

Comment: Leave date as such is easy, just use `=MAXIFS()` instead.

Comment: For the exclusion, I would recommend you to work with a helper column, but this is extremely difficult: you might use the `MONTH()` function for that, but this might mean that `01/01/2022` and `01/01/1980` are of the same month, so you might need to take the `YEAR()` into account. Another way to check a difference of two months is to check the integer difference, but will you check on (30+31) (which will be wrong in summer) or on (31+31) (which will be wrong in February), ...? I guess that you might better write a UDF (User-Defined Function) for checking the month difference.

Comment: Apparently, there is the `EDATE()` function for calculating a month-based difference. Interesting :-)